# SIGSEGV with malloc() in C

Tags: c, malloc, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program in C which uses `malloc()` to allocate memory for a 2d array, then I have to fill this array with data from a file (4 columns, 559 rows of numbers).

My program does compile, but it gives a SIGSEGV error in runtime.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    FILE *pf;
    pf = fopen("Union_sin.txt","r");

    int rows = 559;
    int columns = 4;
    int i =0;
    int j=0;
    float **matrix;
    matrix = (float **)malloc(rows*sizeof(float *));
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        matrix[i] = (float *)malloc(columns*sizeof(float *));
    }

    for (i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for (j=0; j<columns; j++)
                fscanf(pf,"%f\t",&matrix[i][j]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<columns;j++){
            printf("%f\t", matrix[i][j]);}
        printf("\n");}
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++) free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
    return 0;}
```

As you can imagine I am not very skilled so, please, try to be kind and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
   matrix[i] = (float *)malloc(columns*sizeof(float *));
```

Should be

```
   matrix[i] = malloc(columns*sizeof(float));
```

Note that as well as allocating the correct amount of memory, the redundant and dangerous cast has been removed. (You should remove the cast on the first malloc too.)

Another problem: you are totally failing to check for errors on the call to fopen. Assuming that the file has been successfully opened is a recipe for disaster. Structure your code like this:

```
FILE * pf = fopen("Union_sin.txt","r");
if (f == NULL)
{
    // report error
}
else
{
    // do your stuff

    fclose(pf);
}
```

Comment: It's usually better to use `sizeof(**matrix)`. So `sizeof(*matrix)` for the first malloc and `sizeof(**matrix)` for the second one.

Comment: The `malloc` argument is an error and needs to be fixed, but it's not likely to be the problem. Typically `float` is 32 bits, and `float*` is either 32 or 64 bits, so using `sizeof (float *)` will probably happen to allocate either the right amount of memory or too much.

Comment: @Keith: true - I was just fixing the bugs in the order that I found them. Having said that though, this could be Turbo C with 16 bit pointers (not uncommon in the colleges of countries in the developing world).

Comment: Thank you. It works now!

Just one more question: how can I know if my `float` is 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: It's most likely 32 bits but `sizeof(float)` will confirm this.